# How do I hook a javascript function in C# Web Browser control?

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, webbrowser-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invoke C# code from JavaScript in a Document in a WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694028/invoke-c-sharp-code-from-javascript-in-a-document-in-a-webbrowser)

Not sure that this would be possible with the WinForms browser control, but I would like to somehow setup a hook or callback that I can define a function from C# to javascript, when the javascript calls that function I would like it to execute a C# method.  A simple example would be that I am writing a web application and running it inside a C# WinForms native client (so it appears to be a real windows program.)  I need to expose file i/o and directory iteration methods to the Javascript so that my web application can access the file system without needing to load any additional java applets or flash.

Please note I am not requesting third party libraries that would expose this functionality, I am asked for resources or an explanation on how I can create this and any other functionality that I might need.

Comment: `WebBrowser.ObjectForScripting` looks like what you need, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx

Comment: ObjectForScripting it is, thanks mark

Comment: Richard appears you are right, my apologies.

Comment: Checkout the Extension Methods code samples I added to the linked answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27467957/262379