# Silverlight / WPF communication

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control showing a Silverlight application. This control is in a WPF application. Obviously this is a bit of a hack to integrate Silverlight with WPF as ultimately neither one knows about each other, they're completely independent.

So what I need is for Silverlight to post a value into the WPF application. What I was thinking was using JavaScript hosted in the .aspx page in the Silverlight application which can be accessed from both Silverlight and WPF. I think it is fairly simple getting data from Silverlight to the .aspx page but I'm not sure how to get the data from the .aspx page to WPF. Ideally I don't want WPF to have to call for the data, I want it to be posted from Silverlight and appear in the WPF application without WPF having to do anything except receive and display the data.

Hmm...hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you have server communication, you can use WCF or socket. Silverlight call the server and the server call the WPF via polling duplex... But it's not a local communication...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight to/from JavaScript: see here

[MSDN - Making Silverlight Scriptable by JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645085%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

WPF to/from JavaScript: see here

[Stack Overflow - Invoke C# code from JavaScript in a Document in a WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694028/invoke-c-sharp-code-from-javascript-in-a-document-in-a-webbrowser)

[Code project - Working with webbrowser in wpf](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article840-working-with-webbrowser-in-wpf-.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, the third link had exactly what I was looking for.