# Rules to be followed to get window.external work

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, wpf, window.external

I found one thing in `javascript` of my `WPF` project. It has called

`window.external.ShowWindow();`

I have found that method is written in class `InteropClass` like below.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class InteropClass
{
    public void ShowWindow()
    {
        // logic
    }
}
```

and that method is called.
I am trying to analyse it, for that I have used already built class like below

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class AnotherClass : SomeDifferentClass
{
    public void AnotherMethod()
    {
        // logic
    }
}
```

and tried to call it as

`window.external.AnotherMethod();`

but it is not working. Error alert says

> AnotherMethod is not supported by window.external object

I know both classes differs in many terms and I can make it work but my question is *What rules to be followed to make this work*, may be like class must be directly inherited from `Object` or some other.

Answer (score 0):

> What you need to do is set the ObjectForScripting property on the web
>   browser control to an object containing the C# methods you want to
>   call from JavaScript.

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3694080/3664659) told me everything I was missing.