# How do you call a C# event with a script that is in a webbrower object?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps-api-3

Good day

I have made a small website for my google api( because I didn't find a way to use it in my C# Form program). The idea is that when I click on the map icon a event needs to trigger in side the C# Program. I am using the [webbrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) tool on my C# From to show my website. I am really hoping this is even possible.

If the above is not possible or if any one has a better idea on how to implement a map on a forms application with icons/buttons it will really help.

I have looked at : [Sharpmap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) -- but my employer doesn't like the look
and              : ThinkGeo] -- it costs money (still a option)

Comment: As in [Invoke C# code from JavaScript in a Document in a WebBrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694028/invoke-c-sharp-code-from-javascript-in-a-document-in-a-webbrowser) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255) describes two-way communication between a web browser control and the form on which it resides, which includes raising events from the browser control to be handled by the form.

A few key details:

In the `Form_Load` event, the control's `ObjectForScripting` property is set to the form:

```
webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
```

In the HTML within the browser control, `window.external` is used to access methods in the 'object for scripting.'

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText =
        "<html><head><script>" +
        "function test(message) { alert(message); }" +
        "</script></head><body><button " +
        "onclick=\"window.external.Test('called from script code')\">" +
        "call client code from script code</button>" +
        "</body></html>";
```

So this:

```
window.external.Test('called from script code')
```

calls the `Test` method within the form, passing `called from script code` as an argument.

```
public void Test(String message)
{
    MessageBox.Show(message, "client code");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx Scott
 I got the From to register my java Script events. All you have to do extra from what Scot said is add these namespaces:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;
```

and this above your form obj

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public partial class Form1 : Form
   {...}
```

I also didn't use webBrowser1.DocumentText I used webBrowser1.Url-- i made the website 1st and just added it. There is problem with this the website needs to be hosted so use XAMPP to local host it(for testing)