# C# Webbrowsercontrol with Proxy and Call from Javascript to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, proxy, webbrowser-control

I combined the functionality of webbrowsercontrol ObjectForScripting [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694028/invoke-c-sharp-code-from-javascript-in-a-document-in-a-webbrowser) to call C# functions from javascript and a proxy for that webbrowser control [(source)](http://www.journeyintocode.com/2013/08/c-webbrowser-control-proxy.html).

Each function on its own works. But when i combine them, the calls from javascript doesn't work anymore. Errormessage is

> Object doesn't support property or method "Test"

Sourcecode for an example is on the bottom.

You can try both functionality when commenting and uncommenting this block in `Form1_Load`

```
// Comment this block for Callback working
object obj = webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
IOleObject oc = obj as IOleObject;
oc.SetClientSite(Proxy as IOleClientSite);
```

I guess the problem is the function `QueryService` from the interface `IServiceProvider`. I tried to pin it down with the GUID from `Scriptmanager` but found no solution.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProxyTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    proxy Proxy = new proxy();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");

        // Comment this block for Callback working
        object obj = webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
        IOleObject oc = obj as IOleObject;
        oc.SetClientSite(Proxy as IOleClientSite);

        //Proxy settings are not necessary
        Proxy._currentUsername = ""; // Username
        Proxy._currentPassword = ""; // Password
        Proxy.SetProxyServer(""); //IP:PORT

        webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new Scriptmanager();

        Application.DoEvents();

        webBrowser1.DocumentText =
        "<html><head><script>" +
        "function test(message) { alert(message); }" +
        "</script></head><body><button " +
        "onclick=\"window.external.Test('called from script code')\">" +
        "call client code from script code</button>" +
        "</body></html>";
    }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class Scriptmanager
{
    public void Test(string text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
}


public class proxy : IOleClientSite, IServiceProvider, IAuthenticate
{
    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption,
        IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);
    private Guid IID_IAuthenticate = new Guid("79eac9d0-baf9-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b");
    private const int INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION = unchecked((int)0x800C0011);
    private const int S_OK = unchecked((int)0x00000000);
    private const int INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY = 38;
    private const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT = 1;
    private const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY = 3;
    internal string _currentUsername;
    internal string _currentPassword;



    internal void SetProxyServer(string proxy)
    {
        //Create structure
        INTERNET_PROXY_INFO proxyInfo = new INTERNET_PROXY_INFO();

        if (proxy == null)
        {
            proxyInfo.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT;
        }
        else
        {
            proxyInfo.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
            proxyInfo.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(proxy);
            proxyInfo.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local");
        }

        // Allocate memory
        IntPtr proxyInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(proxyInfo));

        // Convert structure to IntPtr
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(proxyInfo, proxyInfoPtr, true);
        bool returnValue = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY,
            proxyInfoPtr, Marshal.SizeOf(proxyInfo));
    }

    #region IOleClientSite Members

    public void SaveObject()
    {
        // TODO:  Add Form1.SaveObject implementation
    }

    public void GetMoniker(uint dwAssign, uint dwWhichMoniker, object ppmk)
    {
        // TODO:  Add Form1.GetMoniker implementation
    }

    public void GetContainer(object ppContainer)
    {
        ppContainer = this;
    }

    public void ShowObject()
    {
        // TODO:  Add Form1.ShowObject implementation
    }

    public void OnShowWindow(bool fShow)
    {
        // TODO:  Add Form1.OnShowWindow implementation
    }

    public void RequestNewObjectLayout()
    {
        // TODO:  Add Form1.RequestNewObjectLayout implementation
    }

    #endregion

    #region IServiceProvider Members

    public int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvObject)
    {
        int nRet = guidService.CompareTo(IID_IAuthenticate);
        if (nRet == 0)
        {
            nRet = riid.CompareTo(IID_IAuthenticate);
            if (nRet == 0)
            {
                ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this, typeof(IAuthenticate));
                return S_OK;
            }
        }

        ppvObject = new IntPtr();
        return INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IAuthenticate Members

    public int Authenticate(ref IntPtr phwnd, ref IntPtr pszUsername, ref IntPtr pszPassword)
    {
        IntPtr sUser = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAuto(_currentUsername);
        IntPtr sPassword = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAuto(_currentPassword);

        pszUsername = sUser;
        pszPassword = sPassword;
        return S_OK;
    }

    #endregion
}

public struct INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
{
    public int dwAccessType;
    public IntPtr proxy;
    public IntPtr proxyBypass;
}

#region COM Interfaces

[ComImport, Guid("00000112-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IOleObject
{
    void SetClientSite(IOleClientSite pClientSite);
    void GetClientSite(IOleClientSite ppClientSite);
    void SetHostNames(object szContainerApp, object szContainerObj);
    void Close(uint dwSaveOption);
    void SetMoniker(uint dwWhichMoniker, object pmk);
    void GetMoniker(uint dwAssign, uint dwWhichMoniker, object ppmk);
    void InitFromData(IDataObject pDataObject, bool
        fCreation, uint dwReserved);
    void GetClipboardData(uint dwReserved, IDataObject ppDataObject);
    void DoVerb(uint iVerb, uint lpmsg, object pActiveSite,
        uint lindex, uint hwndParent, uint lprcPosRect);
    void EnumVerbs(object ppEnumOleVerb);
    void Update();
    void IsUpToDate();
    void GetUserClassID(uint pClsid);
    void GetUserType(uint dwFormOfType, uint pszUserType);
    void SetExtent(uint dwDrawAspect, uint psizel);
    void GetExtent(uint dwDrawAspect, uint psizel);
    void Advise(object pAdvSink, uint pdwConnection);
    void Unadvise(uint dwConnection);
    void EnumAdvise(object ppenumAdvise);
    void GetMiscStatus(uint dwAspect, uint pdwStatus);
    void SetColorScheme(object pLogpal);
}

[ComImport, Guid("00000118-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IOleClientSite
{
    void SaveObject();
    void GetMoniker(uint dwAssign, uint dwWhichMoniker, object ppmk);
    void GetContainer(object ppContainer);
    void ShowObject();
    void OnShowWindow(bool fShow);
    void RequestNewObjectLayout();
}

[ComImport, GuidAttribute("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa"),
InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
ComVisible(false)]
public interface IServiceProvider
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvObject);
}

[ComImport, GuidAttribute("79EAC9D0-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B"),
InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
ComVisible(false)]
public interface IAuthenticate
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int Authenticate(ref IntPtr phwnd, ref IntPtr pszUsername, ref IntPtr pszPassword);
}

#endregion
}
```

**Update 01.11.2016**
This tip from Sheng Jiang 蒋晟 was really good. I almost have a working example. The messagebox is shown after the click. Sadly afterwards comes a InvalidVariant exception. Anybody has a guess what's wrong. I'm stuck again. Here is the current code.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace ProxyTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    proxy Proxy = new proxy();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
        // Comment this block for Callback working
        object obj = webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
        IOleObject oc = obj as IOleObject;
        oc.SetClientSite(Proxy as IOleClientSite);

        //Proxy settings are not necessary
        Proxy._currentUsername = ""; // Username
        Proxy._currentPassword = ""; // Password
        Proxy.SetProxyServer(""); //IP:PORT


        webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new Scriptmanager();

        Application.DoEvents();

        webBrowser1.DocumentText =
        "<html><head><script>" +
        "function test(message) { alert(message); }" +
        "</script></head><body><button " +
        "onclick=\"window.external.Test('called from script code')\">" +
        "call client code from script code</button>" +
        "</body></html>";

    }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IScriptmanager
{
    void Test(string text);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class Scriptmanager : IScriptmanager
{
    public void Test(string text)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
}


public class proxy : IOleClientSite, IServiceProvider, IAuthenticate, IDocHostUIHandler
{
    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption,
        IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);
    private Guid IID_IAuthenticate = new Guid("79eac9d0-baf9-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b");
    private const int INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION = unchecked((int)0x800C0011);
    private const int S_OK = unchecked((int)0x00000000);
    private const int INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY = 38;
    private const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT = 1;
    private const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY = 3;
    internal string _currentUsername;
    internal string _currentPassword;

    IDocHostUIHandler _baseIDocHostUIHandler;

    internal void SetProxyServer(string proxy)
    {

        //Create structure
        INTERNET_PROXY_INFO proxyInfo = new INTERNET_PROXY_INFO();

        if (proxy == null)
        {
            proxyInfo.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT;
        }
        else
        {
            proxyInfo.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
            proxyInfo.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(proxy);
            proxyInfo.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local");
        }

        // Allocate memory
        IntPtr proxyInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(proxyInfo));

        // Convert structure to IntPtr
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(proxyInfo, proxyInfoPtr, true);
        bool returnValue = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY,
            proxyInfoPtr, Marshal.SizeOf(proxyInfo));
    }

    #region IOleClientSite Members

    public void SaveObject()
    {
        // TODO:  Add Form1.SaveObject implementation
    }

    public void GetMoniker(uint dwAssign, uint dwWhichMoniker, object ppmk)
    {
        // TODO:  Add Form1.GetMoniker implementation
    }

    public void GetContainer(object ppContainer)
    {
        ppContainer = this;
    }

    public void ShowObject()
    {
        // TODO:  Add Form1.ShowObject implementation
    }

    public void OnShowWindow(bool fShow)
    {
        // TODO:  Add Form1.OnShowWindow implementation
    }

    public void RequestNewObjectLayout()
    {
        // TODO:  Add Form1.RequestNewObjectLayout implementation
    }

    #endregion

    #region IServiceProvider Members

    public int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvObject)
    {
        int nRet = guidService.CompareTo(IID_IAuthenticate);
        if (nRet == 0)
        {
            nRet = riid.CompareTo(IID_IAuthenticate);
            if (nRet == 0)
            {
                ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(this, typeof(IAuthenticate));
                return S_OK;
            }
        }

        ppvObject = new IntPtr();
        return INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IAuthenticate Members

    public int Authenticate(ref IntPtr phwnd, ref IntPtr pszUsername, ref IntPtr pszPassword)
    {
        IntPtr sUser = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAuto(_currentUsername);
        IntPtr sPassword = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAuto(_currentPassword);

        pszUsername = sUser;
        pszPassword = sPassword;
        return S_OK;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDocHostUIHandler Members
    public uint ShowContextMenu(uint dwID, ref tagPOINT ppt, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object pcmdtReserved, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object pdispReserved)
    {
        const int MenuNotHandled = 1;
        return MenuNotHandled;
    }

    public void GetHostInfo(ref DOCHOSTUIINFO pInfo)
    {
        // turn three flags on
        pInfo.dwFlags |= (uint)(DOCHOSTUIFLAG.DOCHOSTUIFLAG_SCROLL_NO |
         DOCHOSTUIFLAG.DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NO3DBORDER |
          DOCHOSTUIFLAG.DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DISABLE_SCRIPT_INACTIVE);
    }

    public void ShowUI(uint dwID, ref object pActiveObject, ref object pCommandTarget, ref object pFrame, ref object pDoc)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void HideUI()
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void UpdateUI()
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void EnableModeless(int fEnable)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnDocWindowActivate(int fActivate)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnFrameWindowActivate(int fActivate)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ResizeBorder(ref tagRECT prcBorder, int pUIWindow, int fFrameWindow)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public uint TranslateAccelerator(ref tagMSG lpMsg, ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID)
    {
        const int KillAccelerator = 0;
        const int AllowAccelerator = 1;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;

        if (lpMsg.message != WM_KEYDOWN)
            // allow message
            return AllowAccelerator;

        if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) != Keys.Control)
            return AllowAccelerator;

        // disable the Ctrl-N and Ctrl-P accelerators
        lpMsg.wParam &= 0xFF; // get the virtual keycode
        if ((lpMsg.wParam == 'N') || ((lpMsg.wParam == 'P')))
            return KillAccelerator;

        // allow everything else
        return AllowAccelerator;
    }

    public void GetOptionKeyPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] ref string pchKey, uint dw)
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public uint GetDropTarget(int pDropTarget, ref int ppDropTarget)
    {
        const int S_OK = 0;
        return S_OK;
    }
    //public object GetDropTarget(ref object pDropTarget)
    //{
    //    return pDropTarget;
    //}

    public void GetExternal([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] out object ppDispatch)
    {
        ppDispatch = new Scriptmanager();

    }

    public uint TranslateUrl(uint dwTranslate, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string pchURLIn, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] ref string ppchURLOut)
    {
        const int NotTranslated = 1;

        return NotTranslated;
    }

    public IDataObject FilterDataObject(IDataObject pDO)
    {
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}

public struct INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
{
    public int dwAccessType;
    public IntPtr proxy;
    public IntPtr proxyBypass;
}

public struct tagRECT
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct tagPOINT
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

public enum DOCHOSTUITYPE
{
    DOCHOSTUITYPE_BROWSE = 0,
    DOCHOSTUITYPE_AUTHOR = 1
}

public enum DOCHOSTUIDBLCLK
{
    DOCHOSTUIDBLCLK_DEFAULT = 0,
    DOCHOSTUIDBLCLK_SHOWPROPERTIES = 1,
    DOCHOSTUIDBLCLK_SHOWCODE = 2
}

[Flags()]
public enum DOCHOSTUIFLAG
{
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DIALOG = 0x00000001,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DISABLE_HELP_MENU = 0x00000002,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NO3DBORDER = 0x00000004,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_SCROLL_NO = 0x00000008,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DISABLE_SCRIPT_INACTIVE = 0x00000010,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_OPENNEWWIN = 0x00000020,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DISABLE_OFFSCREEN = 0x00000040,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_FLAT_SCROLLBAR = 0x00000080,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DIV_BLOCKDEFAULT = 0x00000100,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_ACTIVATE_CLIENTHIT_ONLY = 0x00000200,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_OVERRIDEBEHAVIORFACTORY = 0x00000400,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_CODEPAGELINKEDFONTS = 0x00000800,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_URL_ENCODING_DISABLE_UTF8 = 0x00001000,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_URL_ENCODING_ENABLE_UTF8 = 0x00002000,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_ENABLE_FORMS_AUTOCOMPLETE = 0x00004000,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_ENABLE_INPLACE_NAVIGATION = 0x00010000,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_IME_ENABLE_RECONVERSION = 0x00020000,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_THEME = 0x00040000,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NOTHEME = 0x00080000,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NOPICS = 0x00100000,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NO3DOUTERBORDER = 0x00200000,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DISABLE_EDIT_NS_FIXUP = 0x400000,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_LOCAL_MACHINE_ACCESS_CHECK = 0x800000,
    DOCHOSTUIFLAG_DISABLE_UNTRUSTEDPROTOCOL = 0x1000000
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DOCHOSTUIINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint dwDoubleClick;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string pchHostCss;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    public string pchHostNS;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct tagMSG
{
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    public uint message;
    public uint wParam;
    public int lParam;
    public uint time;
    public tagPOINT pt;
}

#region COM Interfaces

[ComImport, Guid("00000112-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IOleObject
{
    void SetClientSite(IOleClientSite pClientSite);
    void GetClientSite(IOleClientSite ppClientSite);
    void SetHostNames(object szContainerApp, object szContainerObj);
    void Close(uint dwSaveOption);
    void SetMoniker(uint dwWhichMoniker, object pmk);
    void GetMoniker(uint dwAssign, uint dwWhichMoniker, object ppmk);
    void InitFromData(IDataObject pDataObject, bool
        fCreation, uint dwReserved);
    void GetClipboardData(uint dwReserved, IDataObject ppDataObject);
    void DoVerb(uint iVerb, uint lpmsg, object pActiveSite,
        uint lindex, uint hwndParent, uint lprcPosRect);
    void EnumVerbs(object ppEnumOleVerb);
    void Update();
    void IsUpToDate();
    void GetUserClassID(uint pClsid);
    void GetUserType(uint dwFormOfType, uint pszUserType);
    void SetExtent(uint dwDrawAspect, uint psizel);
    void GetExtent(uint dwDrawAspect, uint psizel);
    void Advise(object pAdvSink, uint pdwConnection);
    void Unadvise(uint dwConnection);
    void EnumAdvise(object ppenumAdvise);
    void GetMiscStatus(uint dwAspect, uint pdwStatus);
    void SetColorScheme(object pLogpal);
}

[ComImport, Guid("00000118-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IOleClientSite
{
    void SaveObject();
    void GetMoniker(uint dwAssign, uint dwWhichMoniker, object ppmk);
    void GetContainer(object ppContainer);
    void ShowObject();
    void OnShowWindow(bool fShow);
    void RequestNewObjectLayout();
}

[ComImport, GuidAttribute("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa"),
InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
ComVisible(false)]
public interface IServiceProvider
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvObject);
}

[ComImport, GuidAttribute("79EAC9D0-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B"),
InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
ComVisible(false)]
public interface IAuthenticate
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int Authenticate(ref IntPtr phwnd, ref IntPtr pszUsername, ref IntPtr pszPassword);
}

[ComImport()]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[GuidAttribute("bd3f23c0-d43e-11cf-893b-00aa00bdce1a")]
public interface IDocHostUIHandler
{
    [PreserveSig]
    uint ShowContextMenu(
    uint dwID,
    ref tagPOINT ppt,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]  object pcmdtReserved,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object pdispReserved
    );

    void GetHostInfo(ref DOCHOSTUIINFO pInfo);

    void ShowUI(uint dwID, ref object pActiveObject, ref object pCommandTarget, ref object pFrame, ref object pDoc);

    void HideUI();

    void UpdateUI();

    void EnableModeless(int fEnable);

    void OnDocWindowActivate(int fActivate);

    void OnFrameWindowActivate(int fActivate);

    void ResizeBorder(ref tagRECT prcBorder, int pUIWindow, int fFrameWindow);

    [PreserveSig]
    uint TranslateAccelerator(ref tagMSG lpMsg, ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdID);

    void GetOptionKeyPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] ref string pchKey, uint dw);

    uint GetDropTarget(int pDropTarget, ref int ppDropTarget);
    //object GetDropTarget(ref object pDropTarget);

    [PreserveSig]
    void GetExternal([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] out object ppDispatch);

    [PreserveSig]
    uint TranslateUrl(
    uint dwTranslate,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string pchURLIn,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] ref string ppchURLOut
    );

    IDataObject FilterDataObject(IDataObject pDO);
}

#endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting has no effect since you are replacing the client site. The default client site in WinForms implements IDocHostUIHandler::GetExternal and returns the value of ObjectForScripting. You can do the same thing in your Proxy class.

Comment: Thank you for that tip. I got it almost working. I explained the current problem in the post. I'm stuck with a InvalidVariant exception after my MessageBox is shown. Do you have another tip?

Comment: which line throws the exception? signature for some methods should use out instead of ref. and return INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION or throw  NotImplementedException (translates to E_NOTIMPL) instead of making a COM method void and do nothing (that translates to S_OK)

Comment: the exception gets thrown from 'Application.Run(new Form1());' in the 'Program.cs'. That's why I have no clue which function is wrong. I found different definitions for the 'IDocHostUIHandler'. Is there a reliable source for the definition?

Comment: Yes, there is an internal implementation in WinForms, just use a reflector to see it.

Comment: you probably have "Just my code" enabled in the debugger and native code debugging disabled. Change those settings and try again.