# How to minimize and maximize webapp in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a webapp that has a behavior of a system app, like minimizing and maximizing the windows while the main window is still remain open at the back?..

any suggestion on how I can get the right tools or codes for this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to minimise and maximise the browser window itself?

Comment: no, just to put another webform inside the browser that can minimize or maximize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page can't control size of browser window and definitely can't minimize browser or open new window maximized due to security restrictions on JavaScript in browser.

The only thing page can do is request full-screen with user prompt - [How to make the window full screen with Javascript (stretching all over the screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-the-window-full-screen-with-javascript-stretching-all-over-the-scre)

If you just want to use HTML/JavaScript for your application and don't really need it to render in browser - use WebBrowserControl on WinForms (or other browser hosting solution) to render page and expose way to control size of your own window via to script inside page (i.e. [Invoke C# code from JavaScript in a Document in a WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694028/invoke-c-sharp-code-from-javascript-in-a-document-in-a-webbrowser))

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.